# LG G2 music player hooking into bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, lg-g2

I have a 2012 C250 that I used to hook up to my RAZR MAXX, and was able to control the music (Google Play Music) from the car.

I now have an LG G2, and I noticed in the beginning that the LG player would fire up when I hit my car's commands. If i manually start Play Music, the car will intermittently recognize it, but mostly the control functions are useless. The car will still receive the audio and phone fine however.

I have rooted my phone and frozen the LG player, but no luck. All of my music is on Google Play, so unless there is an app which can play GooglePlay music that plays nicely with my car, I'm kinda stuck.

Anybody have any ideas? Thanks